# I have npm vulnerability issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, react-router-dom

I was doing React App, I need to install react-router-dom, so I typed npm install react-router-dom and I faced this problem. Even I recreated the React Project and reinstalled node.js, the result didn't change.

What I can do to fix the problem?

[image]

Comment: Which 'problem' are you referring to? You have warnings, not errors...

Comment: The printout also gives you a suggestion.

Comment: @BenM I'm new to NPM, won't these warnings cause problems during the project?

Comment: @Akyut Korkmaz they will most likely not. They aren’t “errors”. They are **POTENTIAL** security issues

Comment: The warnings are mostly about missing optional dependencies. These will probably not have any repercussions (hence the description *optional*). The vulnerabilities will not cause issues running your app, but you should run the suggested command to view the details on them and see if you can update packages to remove those vulnerabilities.

Comment: @BrianThompson I run suggested commands but the result is always same. As I said, even I re-installed node.js but anything didn't change.

Comment: Yes, that wouldn't be expected to change anything. The vulnerabilities are in the dependencies you've installed using `npm`, not with `npm` itself. Notice there is another command `npm audit` that will give you details about the vulnerabilities and the packages they originate from.

Comment: @BrianThompson thanks so much for the information. Should I continue doing the project if even warnings haven't been solved? I've no idea what to do in this case because I'm new to using npm.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not something I can evaluate for you. You need to assess the security needs of your application, and try to evaluate the risk of the found vulnerabilities in order to decide if it's something you can live with.

Comment: @BrianThompson So glad for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This means packages installed by npm install or as submodules of other packages have know security issues. Running `npm audit fix` will try to automatically resolve some of these vulnerabilities but is not guaranteed to. Reading the whole message might help next time.

Comment: As you said, I run `npm audit fix` but the result is always same.

Comment: @AykutKorkmaz it just means that no resolutions were found for the packages.

Answer (score -4):

Don't worry about this error. Even if you make a app with create-react-app which is recomended by react you still get this error. Just try out your code it will work just fine

Comment: This is just overall bad advice. Any potential security issue should be handled as good as possible.

Comment: Just today coa and rc npm-package where found to have trojans which steal passwords on dev-computers. This is indeed bad advice.